# Apache Flink 1.9.0 compatibility with Apache Beam version

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

Apache Flink 1.9.0 was released on Aug 22, 2019.  I tried running the Beam word count example from Beam 2.15.0 and Flink runner "beam-runners-flink-1.8" but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an eta for a compatible flink runner artifact for 1.9.0?

I built with Maven dependency below:

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-flink-1.8</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The error mentions job graph deserialization errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but looks like the Apache Beam JIRA is here: jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7730 –